# Java 8 Lambda: Comparator

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator

I want to sort a list with Lambda:

```
List<Message> messagesByDeviceType = new ArrayList<Message>();      
messagesByDeviceType.sort((Message o1, Message o2)->o1.getTime()-o2.getTime());
```

But I got this compilation error:

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int
    - The method sort(Comparator<? super Message>) in the type List<Message> is not applicable for the arguments ((Message o1, Message o2) 
     -> {})
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`Comparator#compareTo` returns an `int`; while `getTime` is obviously `long`.

It would be nicer written like this:

```
.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(Message::getTime))
```

Answer (score 36):

#### Lambda

The lambda can be seen as the shorthand of somewhat cumbersome anonymous class:

Java8 version:

```
Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> o1.getTime() - o2.getTime());
```

Pre-Java8 version:

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Message>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Message o1, Message o2) {
            return o1.getTime() - o2.getTime();
        }
    });
```

So, every time you are confused how to write a right lambda, you may try to write a pre-lambda version, and see how it is wrong.

#### Application

In your specific problem, you can see the `compare` returns `int`, where your `getTime` returns long, which is the source of error.

You may use either method as other answer method, like:

```
Long.compare(o1.getTime(),o2.getTime())
```

#### Notice

- You should avoid using `-` in `Comparator`, which may causes overflow, in some cases, and crash your program.

Answer (score 24):

The `Comparator`'s `compare()` method must return an `int`, and it seems yours is returning a `long`.

You can change it to:

```
(Message o1, Message o2)->Long.compare(o1.getTime(),o2.getTime())
```

This is assuming (based on your error message) that `o1.getTime()` returns a `long`.

Comment: I think they can directly use long compare method like o1.getTime().compareTo(o1.getTime()). as Long wrapper class has implemented Comparable interface.

Answer (score 16):

**Comparator**

We use comparator interface to sort homogeneous and heterogeneous elements for default, customized sorting order.

> ```
> int compare(T o1, T o2);
> ```
>
> it takes two arguments for ordering. Returns a
>
> ```
>     negative integer(-1) « if first argument is less than the other
>     zero             (0) « if both are equal
>     positive integer (1) « if first greater than the second.
> ```

**[Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)** *how to sort a list of objects in [prior versions of Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31244596/5081877) using inner Classes.*

An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.

```
Comparator<Employee> timeCompare = new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        return e1.getCreationTime().compareTo( e2.getCreationTime() );
    }
};
```

**Java 8 [`Lambda Expressions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) uing compare method**

> *A lambda expression is like a method: it provides a list of formal parameters and a body - an expression or block - expressed in terms of those parameters.*
>
> [LambdaExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27): **`LambdaParameters -> LambdaBody`**
>
> *Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in a lambda expression must either be declared final or be effectively final, or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.*

```
Comparator<Employee> functional_semantics = (e1, e2) -> {
   return e1.getCreationTime().compareTo( e2.getCreationTime() );
};
```

---

Basic Sort with Lambda Support

```
Comparator<Employee> timeCompareLambda = (o1, o2) -> (int) ( o1.getCreationTime() - o2.getCreationTime());
Collections.sort(java8, timeCompareLambda );
```

Using **Extracted Key and [Comparing method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-)**: *A comparator that compares by an extracted key. Pass references using :: keyword.*

> ```
> static <T> Comparator<T> comparingLong(ToLongFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)
> ```

```
ToLongFunction<Employee> keyExtracor = Employee::getCreationTime;
Comparator<Employee> byTime = Comparator.comparingLong( Employee::getCreationTime );
```

Sample Test Code:

```
public class Lambda_Long_Comparator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> java7 = getEmployees();

        // Sort with Inner Class
        Comparator<Employee> timeCompare = new Comparator<Employee>() {
            @Override public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
                return e1.getCreationTime().compareTo( e2.getCreationTime() );
            }
        };

        // Collections.sort(list); // Defaults to Comparable<T> « @compareTo(o1)
        Collections.sort(java7, timeCompare); // Comparator<T> « @compare (o1,o2)
        System.out.println("Java < 8 \n"+ java7);

        List<Employee> java8 = getEmployees();
        Collections.sort(java8, Comparator
                .comparing( Employee::getCreationTime )
                .thenComparing( Employee::getName ));
        //java8.forEach((emp)-> System.out.println(emp));
        System.out.println("Java 8 \n"+java8);
    }

    static List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        list.add( new Employee(4, "Yash", date.getTime()+7));
        list.add( new Employee(2, "Raju", date.getTime()+1));
        list.add( new Employee(4, "Yas", date.getTime()));
        list.add( new Employee(7, "Sam", date.getTime()-4));
        list.add( new Employee(8, "John", date.getTime()));
        return list;
    }
}
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Long creationTime;

    public Employee(Integer id, String name, Long creationTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }

    @Override public int compareTo(Employee e) {
        return this.id.compareTo(e.id);
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "\n["+this.id+","+this.name+","+this.creationTime+"]";
    }

    // Other getter and setter methods
}
```

---

See these posts also:

- [Java 8 Tutorial](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/03/16/java-8-tutorial/)
- [Java8 Lambdas vs Anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22637900/5081877)
- [Lambda vs anonymous inner class performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24764118/5081877)

Answer (score 4):

You should change

> ```
>  messagesByDeviceType.sort(
>      (Message o1, Message o2) -> o1.getTime() - o2.getTime()
>  );
> ```

to

```
messagesByDeviceType.sort(
    Comparator.comparing((Message m) -> m.getTime())
);
```

That assumes that the value is `Comparable`, which provides a natural sort order.

If you want to add more fields then you can can chain them to the Comparator.  e.g. to sort first by time, and then by sender:

```
messagesByDeviceType.sort(
    Comparator
        .comparing((Message m) -> m.getTime())
        .thenComparing((m)     -> m.getSender())
);
```

To reverse the order of any `Comparator`, chain the `reveresed()` method to it, e.g. to sort first by time descending, and then by sender:

```
messagesByDeviceType.sort(
    Comparator
        .comparing((Message m) -> m.getTime())
        .reversed()
        .thenComparing((m)     -> m.getSender())
);
```

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 1):

The `compare()` method must return an `int`, and it seems yours is returning a `long`.

You can change it this into:

```
Long.compare(o1.getTime(),o2.getTime())
```

Well explained regarding lambda comparator in the below presented video [link](https://youtu.be/r7mYbTmWtUg).

Answer (score 0):

### lamda comparator

```
In the place of Developer write your class name 

    Comparator<Developer> byName = 
        (Developer o1, Developer o2)->o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
```