# Why my lambda is not applicable for comparator?

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

At first, I write the following code, but it can't build.
`Arrays.sort(n, (o1 ,o2) -> o1 % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1);`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6NCh.png)

And then , I write another code to test it.
`Arrays.sort(n,(o1, o2) -> o1 - o2);`
but it has a same error message in vs code.
And then , I try those code in IDEA , and it has different error messages in the following picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0YlN.png)
it says Operator '-' cannot be applied to 'T', 'T.
And then , I rewrite the code : `Arrays.sort(n,(int o1, int o2) -> o1 - o2);`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH4ee.png)
I don't know why my code doesn't work. And I found the code I write yesterday:
`Arrays.sort(envelopes,(int []o1,int []o2) -> o1[0] == o2[0] ? o2[1] - o1[1] :o1[0] - o2[0]);` and it works well.

Comment: Don't post code as pictures. It is text

Comment: Did you have a lokk at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225896/java-8-lambda-comparator) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing one of the warts of Java's type system that made the otherwise nicely backwards compatible lambdas awkward — `int` is a primitive type.

There are no generics over primitive types (yet), so there is no `Comparator<int>`. The signature of the sort method you're trying to use is

`public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`

and `T` cannot be `int` (or `short`, `byte`, etc.).

One way around this is to box your `int`s, e.g. with a stream:

```
Arrays.stream(n).boxed().sorted((i1, i2) -> i1 % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method signature `sort` has the generic type `T`:

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c);
```

Therefore in order to have the behaviour you want, you have to define `n` as an array of `Integer`.

This works correctly:

```java
Integer[] n = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
Arrays.sort(n, (o1 ,o2) -> o1 % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1);
```

A stackoverflow question about generics and primitive types:
[Why don't Java Generics support primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types)