# Lambdas and Method References Over Normal Java methods in a Class

Tags: java, java-8

Is there any performance aspect or other strong points to use lambdas or methods references over normal java methods ?  How the cost of construction of an object or invoking the methods

I want to know the differences between the traditional and Java 8 Updates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java lambdas 20 times slower than anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585444/java-lambdas-20-times-slower-than-anonymous-classes)

Comment: Method referencing has actual advantage over lambdas.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784664/what-is-the-difference-between-declarative-and-imperative-programming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda vs anonymous inner class performance: reducing the load on the ClassLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764118/lambda-vs-anonymous-inner-class-performance-reducing-the-load-on-the-classloade)

Answer (score 1):

There are many advantages of using Java 8 API's over conventional Java methods.

Java 8 basically focus on Functional style(*More Declarative, Less Imperative*) approach,with Java 8 now we can program in an elegant and fluent, functional style, with higher-order functions. This can lead to concise code
that has fewer errors and is easier to understand, maintain, and parallelize.

**On top it :**

1. Favor Immutability
2. Reduce Side Effects
3. Prefer Expressions Over Statements
4. lazy execution

There is hell a lot to add, i just gave my 2cents.

Answer (score 1):

Java has introduced byte code instruction `invokedynamic` to construct the anonymous class and then `generate byte code` for `lambdas`. **So, In case of lambdas java generates the implementation class and generate byte code at runtime**. Once the byte code generates the rest of the step is the same as a normal method call. So, in case of lambda/method ref the `only overhead is constructing an anonymous class and generate its byte at runtime`. So lambdas are bit slower than a normal method call.

Comment: @shyamsanju can please explain a bit your question.

Comment: can we replace of writing a traditional method with any java 8 updated api

Answer (score 1):

I may assume that the question is about `Imperative` vs. `Declarative` programming in Java.

Because lambda/method reference can be compared only to anonymous class performance.

They take different steps before execution:

```
Lambda      vs    Anonymous Class
linkage           class loading
capture           instantiation
invocation        invocation
```

Overall benchmarks show that lambda is a bit faster with "hot" benchmarks and significant faster with "cold" benchmarks.

Regarding complex methods and collections processing there is no overall performance benchmarks like `X` is faster than `Y`.

You should specify a case to compare performance benchmarks, in some cases classic approach can work faster, in some case - functional. I may assume that in most cases classic approach will work faster, especially when working with mutable objects.

But it's much easier to process a collection in a parallel way with functional style. Streams are lazily-executed, what its an advantage.

It's very good feature that Java supports functional programming, streams and lambdas, but they are not silver bullet. Use them wisely.

Comment: Lambda      vs    Anonymous Class , is'nt both have mutual co beneficial relations?

Comment: @Common Man they conceptual relations for a programmer, but they are differently treated but a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There are several write-ups you can google, but they all seem to show that Lambdas are not as performant as for loops and anonymous classes.  I don't know if Java 9 or Java 10 improved the performance of lambdas at all, but I couldn't find anything that seemed to suggest they did.

I think the main benefit for lambdas is read-ability.  That said, I have seen some lambda code that was not very readable at all, so I guess it's like most things where you can abuse it.

Comment: do we need consumer or supplier over normal java methods

Comment: To use a lambda, no.  For instance I can do `myList.stream().map(item -> item.toString).collect(Collectors.toList()) to convert `myList` to a list of `String`s using `toString()`.  But if you were writing your own lambda I believe you have to use `Consumer` or one of it's variants (there's like a BinaryConsumer and some others???).  I haven't done the latter much so I am not 100% sure.