# Local variables in Lambdas vs Anonymous inner classes

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, anonymous-class

While going through the lambda expressions, I came across the below behavior for anonymous inner classes and lambda expressions. What could be the reason behind this?

```
Human h = new Human() {
int a = 2;
@Override
public void sing() {

System.out.println(++a);
}

};

h.sing();
h.sing();
```

**O/P**

```
3
4
```

Whereas for lambdas I get below:

```
Human h = () -> {

int a = 2;
System.out.println(++a);
};

h.sing();
h.sing();

}
```

**O/P**

```
3
3
```

Comment: The one in the anonymous class isn't a local variable, it's a field that stays alive as long as the object does. The one in the lambda is a local variable that only lives inside the method and isn't saved between calls.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401216/can-java-lambdas-have-state/48401440

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are not equivalent. The first function modifies a variable outside of it's scope, whereas in the second example each time you're invoking `h.sing();`, the body of that function is being invoked. That means, `a` variable is instantiated with value 2 every time.

Answer (score 5):

Your lambda is more or less equivalent to:

```
Human h = new Human() {
    @Override
    public void sing() {
        int a = 2;    
        System.out.println(++a);
    }
};
h.sing();
h.sing();
```

There is no way to declare a lambda with directly mutable state.