# Calling menuitems to trigger a separate block of code

Tags: java, menu, actionlistener, tic-tac-toe

I am developing a simple *TicTacToe* game which has a 'player vs player' mode.

I decided to add a menu in which the player could select whether he wants to play with other player or with the computer.

But I could not figure out how to properly call the menu items to trigger the specified code.

I tried *Action listener* but *ActionListener* inside an *ActionListener* doesn't seem to work.

I am new to programming and I searched various websites but Could not seem  to find a solution. I just want the code of *1-vs-1* to be triggered, when the user clicks *1-vs-1* and *1-vs-computer* (this part is not yet written, as you probably got the idea) to be triggered, when user selects *1-vs-computer* from the menu.

Your little time to solve this problem will be a huge help for me!

```
package tictacpractice;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Frame implements ActionListener {
    int value=0;
    JButton reset;
    JButton exit;
    JLabel p1;
    JLabel p2;
    JButton []board;
    int turn;
    String Checker= "";
    String []Checkers= new String[9];
    boolean winner=false;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu Menu;
    JMenuItem item1,item2;

    Frame(){

        turn=1;
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("TicTacThuss");
        frm.setSize(400,400);

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        Menu = new JMenu("Mode");
        Menu.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 32));
        item1 = new JMenuItem("1v1");
        item1.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 32));
        item2 = new JMenuItem("1vc");
        item2.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 32));
        Menu.add(item1);
        Menu.add(item2);
        menuBar.add(Menu);
        frm.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        item2.addActionListener(this);

        reset = new JButton("reset");
        exit = new  JButton ("exit");
        p1 = new JLabel("Player X");
        p2 = new JLabel("Player O");
        board = new JButton[9];

        reset.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel Lowerpanel= new JPanel();
        Lowerpanel.add(reset);
        Lowerpanel.add(exit);

        JPanel Centralpanel= new JPanel();
        Centralpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        //String initiallizer
        for(int c=0; c<9; c++){
            Checkers[c]="";
        }

        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            board[i]=new JButton();
            Centralpanel.add(board[i]);
            board[i].addActionListener(this);
            board[i].setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 72));
        }

        frm.add(Centralpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frm.add(Lowerpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

         value++;
         if(turn==1){

             Checker=" X";
         }
         if(turn==0){

             Checker=" O";
         }

         if(e.getSource()==reset){
             for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
             {
                 board[i].setText("");
                 board[i].setEnabled(true);
                 winner=false;
                 Checkers[i]="";
                 value=0;
                 turn=1;
             }
        }

        if(e.getSource()==exit){

            System.exit(0);

        }

        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            if(e.getSource()==board[i])
            {
                if(turn==1)
                {  
                    board[i].setText("X");
                    board[i].setEnabled(false);
                    Checkers[i]=Checker;

                }
                else{
                    if(turn==0)
                    {    
                        board[i].setText("O");
                        board[i].setEnabled(false);
                        Checkers[i]=Checker;

                    }
                }

                turn=(turn+1)%2;

            }
        }

        //horizontal
        if (Checkers[0].equals(Checkers[1]) && 
            Checkers[1].equals(Checkers[2]) && 
            !Checkers[0].equals("") ) {
            winner = true;
        }
        else if (Checkers[3].equals(Checkers[4]) && 
                 Checkers[4].equals(Checkers[5]) &&
                 !Checkers[3].equals("") ) {
            winner = true;
        }
        else if (Checkers[6].equals(Checkers[7]) && 
                 Checkers[7].equals(Checkers[8]) &&
                 !Checkers[6].equals("") ) {
            winner = true;
        }
        //Verticle

        if (Checkers[0].equals(Checkers[3]) && 
            Checkers[3].equals(Checkers[6]) &&
            !Checkers[0].equals("") ) {
            winner = true;
        }
        else if (Checkers[1].equals(Checkers[4]) && 
                 Checkers[4].equals(Checkers[7]) &&
                 !Checkers[1].equals("") ) {
            winner = true;
        }
        else if (Checkers[2].equals(Checkers[5]) && 
                 Checkers[5].equals(Checkers[8]) &&
                 !Checkers[2].equals("") ) {
            winner = true;
        }
        //Digonals
        if (Checkers[0].equals(Checkers[4]) && 
            Checkers[4].equals(Checkers[8]) 
            && !Checkers[0].equals("") ) {
            winner = true;
        }
        else if (Checkers[2].equals(Checkers[4]) && 
                 Checkers[4].equals(Checkers[6]) &&
                 !Checkers[2].equals("") ) {
            winner = true;
        }


         //Checker
         if(winner){

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player"+Checker+" Wins");

             for (JButton i : board) {
                 i.setEnabled(false);
             }

         }
         else if(!winner && value==9)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," This game is draw ") ;     
         }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering your question, let me give some comment on your current code. 
Currently, by doing

```
 item1.addActionListener(this);
 item2.addActionListener(this);
 reset.addActionListener(this);
 exit.addActionListener(this);
```

you handle all the `ActionEvent`s in the same `actionPerformed` method
(the one within your `Frame` class).
As you already noticed, this makes this `actionPerformed` method very lengthy and hard to maintain
when it comes to adding more buttons and menu-items.

Therefore I suggest you should give separate `actionPerformed` methods to your buttons.
This has the advantage, that each `actionPerformed` method would be rather short and simple.
And you don't need code-lines like `if (e.getSource() == reset)` anymore.

```
reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       // handle click on the "Reset" button
       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
           board[i].setText("");
           board[i].setEnabled(true);
           winner = false;
           Checkers[i] = "";
           value = 0;
           turn = 1;
       }
    }
});
exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       // handle click on the "Exit" button
       System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

(The syntax may look strange at first glance because it uses so-called [anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java).)

And now to your actual question:
You should use the same pattern also for the menu-items:

```
item1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // handle click on the "1-vs-1" menu item
        ...
    }
});
item2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // handle click on the "1-vs-computer" menu item
        ...
    }
});
```

By the way: Since Java 8 you can rewrite the `ActionListener` code from above
in an even more concise and better readable way
by using so-called [lambda-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637900/java8-lambdas-vs-anonymous-classes) instead of anonymous classes:

```
reset.addActionListener(e -> {
    // handle click on the "Reset" button
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        board[i].setText("");
        board[i].setEnabled(true);
        winner = false;
        Checkers[i] = "";
        value = 0;
        turn = 1;
    }
});
exit.addActionListener(e -> {
    // handle click on the "Exit" button
    System.exit(0);
});
item1.addActionListener(e -> {
    // handle click on the "1-vs-1" menu item
    ...
});
item2.addActionListener(e -> {
    // handle click on the "1-vs-computer" menu item
    ...
});
```

Finally, you would not need the `actionPerformed` in your `Frame`class anymore,
and can remove `implements ActionListener` from that class.