# Having trouble understanding Java 8 's Function<>

Tags: java, java-8

As I'm learning how to use various new tools, I ran upon this syntax (Function x -> ...) which I'm having trouble understanding, and I'd love for someone to write equivalent code if possible so that I can understand it better.

```
Function<String, HashSet<String>> asSet = (String x) ->
      new HashSet<String>() {{
        do_something(x);
      }};
```

Any block of code using more traditional syntax and not that weird Function would be greatly appreciated and useful in helping me better my understanding of Java!

Comment: `Function` is just a normal interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html); the `->` syntax isn't particularly related to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java8 Lambdas vs Anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637900/java8-lambdas-vs-anonymous-classes)

Comment: The reason, this code is not understandable, is not the lambda expression. It’s due to the use of the [Double Brace Initialization anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1958636/2711488), which has been maxed out by using it for a statement entirely unrelated to the constructed map. The code is doing the same as `Function<String, HashSet<String>> asSet = x -> { do_something(x); return new HashSet<>(); }`, except that it is more verbose and creates an unintended subclass of `HashSet`, including memory leaks if the containing method is not `static`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be replaced with anonymous class:

```
Function<String, HashSet<String>> asSet = new Function<>() {
    @Override
    public HashSet<String> apply(String s) {
        return new HashSet<>() {{
            do_something(s);
        }};
    }
};
```

You just implement `apply` method from `Function` which is [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

> Note that instances of functional interfaces can be created with lambda expressions, method references, or constructor references.

See more [What is use of Functional Interface in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8/36882003)

Answer (score 0):

Very basically and without explaining the advantages of using [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)s  you can imagine your function to be an analogy of:

```
HashSet<String> anonymousMethod(String x) {
    return doSomething(x);
}
```

...which resides anonymously in your function object.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is called [Lambda Expressions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/) it's used to simplify implementing [Functional Interfaces](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-interfaces-java/).

Functional Interfaces: are interfaces with one function to implement for example you can write:

> // Java program to demonstrate functional interface

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // create anonymous inner class object 
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("New thread created");
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

or

> // Java program to demonstrate Implementation of
>   // functional interface using lambda expressions

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // lambda expression to create the object 
        new Thread(() - > {
            System.out.println("New thread created");
        }).start();
    }
}
```