# object calls itself using lambda, confused

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, anonymous-class

Confused about java 8 lambda expression.

below is an old java way of implementation of functional interface method;

```
 Function<Employee, Employee> employeeFunc=new Function<Employee,Employee>(){

            public Employee apply(Employee f) {
                return f;
            }
        };
```

Is this same as `e->e`  ? Say `e` is an `Employee`.

what is happening when `object->object` executes? please explain

Comment: Why inventing new names? It’s basically equivalent to `f -> f` which is a short-hand for `(Employee f) -> { return f; }`. What’s your actual question? Where in this code is an “object calls itself” happening, as your question’s title suggests?

Comment: It seems you are confused by the `->` operator, which you are interpreting like a C++/C pointer dereference.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Roughly speaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637900/java8-lambdas-vs-anonymous-classes), it's very similar to `e -> e`, or [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#identity()).

As the JLS put it,

> ### [15.27.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4)
>
> At run time, evaluation of a lambda expression **is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object**. Evaluation of a lambda expression is distinct from execution of the lambda body.

It doesn't "call itself", it's a lambda that takes an object and returns that object without any intermediate action.

Answer (score 1):

In a context where a `Function<Employee, Employee>` is accepted, then yes, `e -> e` will behave the same as the implementation you provided. The lambda isn't executed until it is passed an argument, in which case it just returns that same argument.