# Is it possible to write a Java interface from which you could create an anonymous class, but for which you can't create a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous

Is it possible to write a Java interface from which you could create an anonymous class, but for which you can't create a lambda expression?

Why or why not???

Comment: Related - [Java8 Lambdas vs Anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637900/java8-lambdas-vs-anonymous-classes)

Answer (score 4):

Lambda expressions can only be used to implement functional interfaces, i.e. interfaces with exactly one abstract method.

JLS [15.27. Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27) says:

> Evaluation of a lambda expression produces an instance of a functional interface ([§9.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)).

JLS [9.8. Functional Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) says:

> A *functional interface* is an interface that has just one abstract method (aside from the methods of `Object`), and thus represents a single function contract.

So if you want a Java interface for which you can't create a lambda expression, make the interface have 2 or more abstract methods.

Anonymous classes can still implement such an interface, because they support implementation of more than one method.