# From Anonymous class to lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous-class, functional-interface

When using an anonymous class below , the variable `x` us called without problem

```
interface Age { 
    int x = 21; 
    void getAge(); 
} 

class AnonymousDemo  { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Age oj1 = new Age() { 
            @Override
            public void getAge() { 
                // printing age 
                System.out.print("Age is "+x); 
            } 
        }; 
        oj1.getAge(); 
    } 
}
```

But when I use the same code with lambda expression below, an exception occured:

```
interface Age { 
    int x = 21; 
    void getAge(); 
} 

class AnonymousDemo { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Age oj1 = () -> { System.out.print("Age is "+x); };
        oj1.getAge(); 
    } 
}
```

What would be the problem here? Knowing that lambda expression are just an abbreviation to implement anonymous classes.

Comment: What is this exception?

Comment: @mattfreake error: the exception was -> error:cannot find symbol

Comment: Note that "every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly `public`, `static`, and `final`", see [JLS § 9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3).

Comment: That means that it is a constant, so according to the Java Naming Conventions, it should be written in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually lambda expressions aren't "just an abbreviation to implement anonymous classes". The benefit of using lambda expression is that it has direct access to instance of `this` class (the class from which it was called), while anonymous class don't (it has its own `this` instance).

> In other words, anonymous classes introduce a new scope. so that names
>   are resolved from their superclasses and interfaces and can shadow
>   names that occur in the lexically enclosing environment. For lambdas,
>   all names are resolved lexically.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640484
And also

> Lambda performance with Anonymous classes
>
> When application is launched each class file must be loaded and
>   verified.
>
> Anonymous classes are processed by compiler as a new subtype for the
>   given class or interface, so there will be generated a new class file
>   for each.
>
> Lambdas are different at bytecode generation, they are more efficient,
>   used invokedynamic instruction that comes with JDK7.
>
> For Lambdas this instruction is used to delay translate lambda
>   expression in bytecode untill runtime. (instruction will be invoked
>   for the first time only)
>
> As result Lambda expression will becomes a static method(created at
>   runtime). (There is a small difference with stateles and statefull
>   cases, they are resolved via generated method arguments)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874965

For instance:

```
interface Supplier {
   void foo();
}

class A {

   private String name;

   public void doSome() {
      baz(() -> System.out.println(this.name));
   }

   private void baz(Supplier sup){
     sup.foo();
   }
}
```

or

```
class A {

   private String name;

   public void doSome() {
      baz(new Supplier() {
         void foo() {
            System.out.println(A.this.name);
         }
      });
   }

   private void baz(Supplier sup){
     sup.foo();
   }
}
```

I recommend to read this: [Java8 Lambdas vs Anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637900/java8-lambdas-vs-anonymous-classes).

Answer (score 3):

The `x` is not recognized as a field from the `Age` interface. You have to either do a static import (`import static Age.x`) or specify where the `x` comes from:

```
Age oj1 = () -> System.out.print("Age is "+ Age.x);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By doing the static import approach, does it mean to declare the x variable inside the main class as static ? if so do I have to maintain Age.X approach you mentioned ?

Comment: @CheBoss no. he means `import static Age.x` along with your other import statement.