# "Annotated" lambda expression instead of interface with single apply method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

instead of using anonymous classes like so

```
register(new EventListener() {
  @Override
  public void apply(Event e) {
    // do your work
  }
});
```

with java 8 I can use lambda expressions:

```
register(e -> (// do your work));
```

But what if the method in my interface is annotated?

```
interface EventListener {
  @Annotation
  void apply;
}
```

Is it possible to annotate a lambda expression?
(Specifically, I want to use Guava's EventBus.register() method with lambda expressions)

Comment: you can implement an annotated interface method.  Whether the library understands this is another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this:

[Annotating the functional interface of a Lambda Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375891/annotating-the-functional-interface-of-a-lambda-expression)

Basically, you can't directly annotate in a lambda expression, but you can use the extending interface or class and access the annotation by calling `Class#getAnnotatedInterfaces()`. I believe that should answer your question.

Hope this helps,

Santiago

Comment: While the link might answer the question, you should at least include some form of explanation around it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I added a brief explanation.